# Invalid argument type with verbatimTextOutput in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am having a very difficult time getting to understand how Shiny modules work. I am building an app using a Golem template (https://github.com/ThinkR-open/golem).

*Edit* I realized that my error was not tied to any modules, so generated a minimal example. To review the old code, look in the edit history

```
library(shiny)

app_ui <- function() {
  fluidPage(
    textInput(inputId = "test", label = "Labley", value = "val"),
    verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "out", placeholder = "None")
  )
}

app_server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$out <- renderText(expr = input$test)
}

shinyApp(ui = app_ui, server = app_server)
```

This causes:

```
Error in !: invalid argument type
```

How do I get UI to print my text input?

Comment: I have read through all of the Shiny articles and has likewise consulted sources like engineering-shiny.org and mastering-shiny.org, but I simply can't wrap my head around the concepts of reactive*, render*, and modules.

Comment: `text()` runs the `text` function, which is used to add some text on a plot. I think you want `input$text` instead of `text()`.

Comment: Thx for the input! Also, I realized the error was not tied to the modules, so corrected the example to a minimally functional example

Comment: `app_ui <- fluidPage(......)`, not `app_ui <- function() ......`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@KasperThystrupKarstensen the problem here is, that `verbatimTextOutput`'s placeholder argument requires a boolean input (see usage in `?verbatimTextOutput`). However, you passed a string.

This works:

```
library(shiny)

app_ui <- fluidPage(
  textInput(
    inputId = "test",
    label = "Labley",
    value = "val"
  ),
  verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "out", placeholder = FALSE)
)

app_server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$out <- renderText(expr = input$test)
}

shinyApp(ui = app_ui, server = app_server)
```

`?verbatimTextOutput`:

> placeholder: if the output is empty or NULL, should an empty rectangle
> be displayed to serve as a placeholder? (does not affect behavior when
> the the output in nonempty)

Comment: Ahh now I understand, I wrongfully assumed that like most other shiny input* functions, the placeholder argument needed a string.